# MEL script doesn't run properly

Tags: loops, rename, maya, mel

So I have 6 objects. Three of them are with `_L` suffix. And the other 3 have different irrelevant names. I want to rename these as the first 3 objects but switch the `_L` to `R`. I finally was able to do this. But it's curious why I don't get full result when using the commented out line. Basically I only get the first object renamed properly and get the second object just renamed without switching `L` to `R`. And nothing happens with the third one. The error says: "No object matches name" if I run the `for loop` again. I get the second object renamed properly and the third renamed without the switch and so on. I suspect it has to do with variables.

`$list` is holding the spheres.
`$list_old` is holding the other 3 objects.

Thank you.

```
for ( $x = 0; $x < size( $list ); $x++ ) {

    $rename[ $x ] = ( rename( $list_old[ $x ], $list[ $x ] ) ) ;
    $subs[ $x ] = ( substitute( "_L1", $rename[ $x], "_R" ) );
    rename ( $rename[ $x ], $subs[ $x ] ) ;

    // this doesn't work
    rename ( rename[ $x ], ( $subs[ $x ] = (substitute( "_L1", ( $rename[ $x ] = ( rename( $list_old[ $x ], $list[ $x ] ) ) ), "_R" ) ) ) ) ;
    }
```

Comment: maybe this? for ($x=0; $x<size( $list_old ); $x++)

Comment: You do understand that the commented out line tries to rename many times? The second time it does it theres nothing to rename. Please dont write lisp.

Comment: @joojaa, how would you write it? i need to rename everything in the array. why would there be nothing to rename the second time?

Comment: @SAF, the size of list_old and list should be the same. So how would it make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is more cleaner -

```
string $list_old[]; // which holds your sphere with _L suffix
string $list_new[]; // obj which needs the rename with old list but _R 

for ($x=0; $x<size($list_old); $x++)
    {
        string $new_name =(substitute("_L", $list_old[$x], "_R"));
        $rename[$x] = (rename($list_new[$x], $new_name));
    }
```

Generate new name and then substitute.

Comment: sorry for getting back this late. been busy lately. Yes this ismuch cleaner. Though I'm getting "No object matches name" error on the $rename line. Am I missing something?

Comment: Ideally you should not get that error by using the above example. Unless your source list and new list are having same number of object to be updated. 

Can you give a more specific use case? 
Also in cases where you have the different count in the list, you would need to add more check points to validate the string before renaming them.